# Local install, access denied

Tags: 8

This is a local install of Drupal 8.8.1 I have setup for learning drupal dev. I have my route file setup like so, the controller just returns a paginated list:

```
    mymodule.configurations:
  path: '/admin/structure/mymodule_configurations'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule_configurations\Controller\ConfigurationsController::pager'
    _title: 'List of module configurations'
  reuqirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

so when I try to access the page under admin/structure, logged in as an admin I get an access denied message. Shouldn't access content let anyone at all view the page? As an admin shouldn't I see it anyway?

Comment: Requirements key has a typo.

Comment: Ha! So it is, thank you! An extra beer for you if you can guess how long I stared at it without seeing that.

Comment: Your code editor doesn't have spellchecker?